# Vim auto complete, both with current file and dictionary

Tags: vim, autocomplete, code-completion

In Vim we can achieve code completion by either using dictionaries or the current file, to come up with suggestions.
But what I'm looking after is to have both.

My vimrc has the following code completion:

```
"k=uses dictionary, i=uses current and included files, t=tag completion.
set complete-=k
set complete+=k
set dictionary+=/some_path/some_file
```

Using this i can either use a dictionary, or current file.
But what I want is to see both at the same time.

How do I do that?

Comment: BTW: You don't need to `:set-=` / `:set+=` to ensure unique values; Vim handles that automatically. Or do you do this to change the order?!

Comment: I read this here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default completion (`<C-N>` / `<C-P>` in insert mode) uses the sources configured in `'complete'`. If this option value contains `.` and `k`, both current buffer and the dictionary are considered (you might shortly see messages like `Scanning tags...` etc. after triggering completion that indicate the current source being searched).

That's the whole purpose of default completion; in contrast, you have to use different completion commands (e.g. `<C-X><C-K>` for dictionary) to use a *single source*.

---

**Edit**: You need to ensure that the `k` value actually persists; the `~/.vim/view/` suggests you're restoring a saved view; try clearing those views and removing your existing `.viminfo` file to override any old persisted values of `'complete'`.

Comment: having in my vimrc: set complete=k. and then that dictionary line from my answer. I still cannot get the auto complete from the dictionary without going ctrl-x and then ctrl-k.

Comment: Try `:set complete=k,.` (note the comma).  Setting an option in your vimrc is different from having it set while you are editing.  What does `:verbose set complete? dictionary?` tell you while you are editing a file?  For a useful bug report, tell us what you did, not what you didn't do:  I doubt that you tried everything other than `<C-X><C-K>`.  More specifically, did you try `<C-N>` and `<C-P>` without the `<C-X>`?

Comment: it gives me: 'complete=.,w,b,u,t,i
        Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+.vimrc=
  dictionary=~/public_html/unix/vim/dictionary/default
        Last set from ~/.vimrc' cant help but noticing theres no k in the complete options, which is strange for im setting k in the vimrc like you suggested.

Comment: So the root cause is the missing `k` from `'complete'`. The `~/.vim/view/` suggests you're restoring a saved view; try clearing those and removing your existing `.viminfo` file.

Comment: yeah that was it, thank you! feel welcome to post this as the answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Ah, glad we've sorted that out! I've added the resolution to my answer.

Comment: wait now i have another problem, the system always freezes when i try to use auto complete with the dictionary. It just says 'match in file and-then-the-pathfile-to-dicitonary' and freezes like that while in vim. ive tried changing right settings to the dictionary to 777, ive tried putting it in home directory and i have tried manually setting the complete to 'k' and '.' by doing :set complete=k,. but to no avail.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Please don't misuse the comments for further troubleshooting. If this is about automatic completion (with a plugin), this should be a separate question.

Comment: no this is not with a plugin, this is still a mean to the same end. i was thinking of starting a new question but then, im still trying to make that auto complete work both with current file and dictionary.

Comment: and so i made a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968671/vim-freezes-when-using-auto-complete-with-dictionary-as-well-as-current-file