# Vim freezes when using auto-complete with dictionary as well as current file

Tags: vim, dictionary, autocomplete

As was discussed here: [Vim auto complete, both with current file and dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887628/vim-auto-complete-both-with-current-file-and-dictionary),
I am trying to use both dictionary and current file in determining suggestions during auto-complete.
In my vimrc I have the following two lines for auto-complete:

```
set complete=k,.
set dictionary+=pathfile-to-dictionary
```

But then when I press the auto-complete button I get error:

```
match in file the-dictionary-pathfile
```

And the system completely freezes with that error, i have to close the console and start over to get back to where I was.
I've tried changing right settings to the dictionary file to 777 and I have tried putting dictionary file in home directory. Same error.

I have also noticed that the error pops up whenever I have a word both in dictionary and in current file and then try to auto-complete that very word. So it's probably some sort of collision between those two.

How can I use both dictionary and current file for word completion?

Comment: You could try to use the `'verbose'` option to get a hint about what is causing the problem.

Comment: That does not look like an error message.  I think that vim found one match and is still looking for others.  What happens if you try `:set dictionary=pathfile-to-dictionary` instead of using `+=`?  How large are the dictionaries you are using?

Comment: I get the same message and the system freezes. but strangely i can make a few auto completes without problem before that. I removed the line from my vimrc, deleted the view folder under .vim/view and installed the dictionary via get but same outcome.

Comment: I tried setting it on verbose but it doesn't give me any more information upon freezing. The dictionary i'm using is five lines long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize:  I asked for more information without trying to reproduce the problem.  I think you are right about having the same words, or at least possible matches, in both places.

It does look like a bug.  I find that `<C-C>` once or twice gets me out; I do not have to do anything drastic.

I find that the problem goes away if I reverse the order:

```
:set complete=.,k
```

Comment: I tried it but the system still freezes. <C-C> twice does get me out though.

Comment: What version (and patch level) of vim are you using?  (Mine is 7.3.646.)  You did `:set complete=.,k` from the command line, right, not in your vimrc file?  The dictionary I used was `cat catharsis catechism catastrophe`; the file I was editing was `cat dog fish`; and I completed "ca" by typing `<C-P>`.

Comment: ok it works now, i think it was some view file messing with it.

Comment: the dictionary doesnt seem to work with special characters like '(' etc. do you know how to add such characters to it?

Comment: According to `:help 'dictionary'`, `... Each file should contain a list of words.  This can be one word per line, or several words per line, separated by non-keyword characters (white space is preferred).  Maximum line length is 510 bytes.`  In other words, a charaacter like `(` will be interpreted as separating words.  If you want it to be treated as part of a word, add it to the `'iskeyword'` option:  `:set isk+=(`.  (I just tested, and now "foo(bar" is recognized as one word, not two.)

Comment: that does have a drawback, now the system thinks 'somefunction(somearg)' is a single word. that makes for instance 'caw' in normal mode delete both the function and the arg, which is unwanted. do you know if there is any way to set auto complete without chaing vim's definition of a word?

Comment: No, I think that the dictionary format (as used by the `'dictionnary'` and `'complete'` options) uses the same definition of a word as the `aw` text object (as well as motions like `w` and `e`).

Answer (score 3):

That's a bug, because Vim starts an endless loop. I made a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/FqlxQ1NrB2M/hgJFmizXpYsJ) and sent it to the vim-dev mailinglist.