# Vim autocomplete to store words between documents

Tags: vim

### User statement:

I use Vim to write many technical text documents, including emails.

### Question:

Is it possible to "store unique words" from past documents in some `.vim/file` that would be automatically loaded when any future file is opened and the  `Ctrl+N` command is issued? I know others have asked about pointing to a dictionary file in addition to the current file (e.g., [Vim auto complete, both with current file and dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887628/vim-auto-complete-both-with-current-file-and-dictionary)) but I'd rather the process was dynamic.

### Ideal behavior:

I'd like to write one email containing `Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`. Then, in some future email, I'd like to start writing `Superc` and then `Ctrl+N` would complete the word.

### Further thoughts/requests:

1. I assume there is concern about such a "carryover file" growing excessively large over time. It would be great if it is possible to prevent "words shorter than `K` characters" from being stored.
2. I'm also willing/interested in manually editing such a file.

Comment: This was answered by another user in the [vim stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37833/26495).